# Validations not done while submitting rails form via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I did a simple rails form with two user inputs , name and email. I'm using rails 3.1, so I used `:remote => true` in my `form_for` tag. I also created a `create.js.erb` and added corresponding `format.js` in the `users_controller.rb`.

I added the following lines in `create.js.erb`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').html("<h1>Registration Successful</h1>")
});
```

Now the problem is that when I click the submit button, with empty fields, it does not show validations error messages that I have added in the `user.rb` model file. Instead, it will show me `registration successful` message.

Is there some easy way to circumvent this problems in rails. Also please note that I'm very bad at javascript, so please be nice to me.

controller code for create

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        #UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Show us your controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't show the errors is because you are not telling it to, you are simply telling it to write "Registration Successful".  You could try:

```
<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
  $('body').prepend("<h1><%=error%></h1>");
<% end %>
```

This assumes that your controller has the following or something similar:

```
@user = User.create(params[:user])
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.  If not, some controller code will be required to help further.

Comment: Is it not possible, that once the submit button is clicked, before submitting the form, the validations error shows, the rails way

Comment: You will want to validate both the client and the server.  There is a gem that helps combine the two though, check out the client_side_validations gem.  https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations

Comment: OMG !! I think I saw this gem in one of the railcasts screencast. Thank you for reminding me.